# jquery resizable() not working (with example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

Please see this work in progress:

http://rawgit.com/jfix/cover-image-position/master/index.html

My goal is to allow drag and drop from the desktop onto this page, and following that to drag the image around as well as to resize it. You should be able to drop an image onto the page and to drag it around.

However, *what doesn't work is the resizing of the image*. There is no handle displayed at the frame around the image and it's impossible to resize it.  No errors in the console.

The relevant code is here:

```
hdl.resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    autoHide: true,
    alsoResize: "#coverimage",
    handles: 'all',
    resize: function(event, ui) {
    cvr
        .css('left', ui.position.left)
        .css('top', ui.position.top);
    }
});
```

where `hdl` is a short form for the `$('#handler')` in the `assets/script.js` file. I should note that this has been copied almost verbatim from this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nL5ew/ where it works fine, obviously.

I can't seem to find the problem with my code. Thank you for any eagle-eyed insights you may have.

Comment: on your page somehow the code which you have mentioned doesnt run...

Comment: @RRR if you mean that there is no image on the page (except the overlay) that's normal and expected, you have to drag and drop an image from your desktop onto it. If that's what you mean by "doesn't run".

Comment: what i meant was few functions in your script is not getting recognized... maybe prob with version of jQuery or jQuery UI... I tried to recreate the scenario in jsfiddle by copying your code and it runs fine with jQuery verion 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2 :) you can check the demo here https://jsfiddle.net/x3tbre8p/

Comment: NOTE:  I didnt change any of the HTML, CSS or jQuery just changed the version of jQuery and jQuery UI :)

Comment: @RRR great, I'll downgrade the libraries to the ones you indicate, fingers crossed ... thanks!

Comment: @RRR I have inspected the code in the JSFiddle line by line and finally found that the JQuery UI CSS file was included in the fiddle but not in my code. Adding this file fixes the issue! Thanks a lot for your helpful comments. This is the line in question: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`.

Comment: glad you found a fix :) happy to help :)

Comment: You should edit title of the question or someplace easy to read, that the issue is fixed. ;-)

Comment: @Lombas, no its not necessary the op should mark an answer as accepted. If the answer was posted as a comment the author should post an answer

Comment: Do not edit "solved" into the title, instead post the solution and accept it (or accept an existing if it solved your problem)

Comment: @andrew there's just one answer and its solution is not acceptable. The comments to the question however helped me figure out the problem. What now? :-)

Comment: as @KevinB says, you can answer your own question and accept it, you may even get upvotes on the answer too thus improving your reputation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having inspected @RRR's JSFiddle, and comparing it line by line with my code, I ended up discovering that I was not including one, as it turns out, vital CSS file from the JQuery UI suite.  This is the line that was missing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

In all fairness the correct solution was provided by @RRR, unfortunately not in a full-blown answer but just in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

use this syntax for better result:

```
 $(selector, context).resizable({option1: value1, option2: value2..... });
```

Comment: @Valsal, can you elaborate what this will change? I can see that you're adding a `context` parameter next to the selector. What should I use for it?